# Multithreaded Priority Queue With Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I follow this example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_multithreading.htm

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import queue
import threading
import time

exitFlag = 0

class myThread (threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, threadID, name, q):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.threadID = threadID
      self.name = name
      self.q = q
   def run(self):
      print ("Starting " + self.name)
      process_data(self.name, self.q)
      print ("Exiting " + self.name)

def process_data(threadName, q):
   while not exitFlag:
      queueLock.acquire()
      if not workQueue.empty():
         data = q.get()
         queueLock.release()
         print ("%s processing %s" % (threadName, data))
      else:
         queueLock.release()
         time.sleep(1)

threadList = ["Thread-1", "Thread-2", "Thread-3"]
nameList = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
queueLock = threading.Lock()
workQueue = queue.Queue(10)
threads = []
threadID = 1

# Create new threads
for tName in threadList:
   thread = myThread(threadID, tName, workQueue)
   thread.start()
   threads.append(thread)
   threadID += 1

# Fill the queue
queueLock.acquire()
for word in nameList:
   workQueue.put(word)
queueLock.release()

# Wait for queue to empty
while not workQueue.empty():
   pass

# Notify threads it's time to exit
exitFlag = 1

# Wait for all threads to complete
for t in threads:
   t.join()
print ("Exiting Main Thread")
```

But my RESULT(python 3.7) are:

> Starting Thread-1
>
> Starting Thread-2
>
> Starting Thread-3
>
> Thread-3 processing One
>
> Thread-3 processing Two
>
> Thread-3 processing Three
>
> Thread-3 processing Four
>
> Thread-3 processing Five
>
> Exiting Thread-3
>
> Exiting Thread-1
>
> Exiting Thread-2
>
> Exiting Main Thread

Only last thread work
How can I do this in correctly?
Thank